# Send Universal Push Notifications - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have finished this tutorial here
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services
and now i can send a push notification to my device using my application. 
However i cannot figure out how to send push notifications not just to my specific device token but to all devices with my application.

Comment: Consider [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the message to each device individually, i.e.: in a loop

Comment: How do i make the loop so i don't have to individually get each device token

Comment: If you don't have infrastructure set up go with MДΓΓ БДLL suggestions and use Urban Airship.

Answer (score 0):

Apples Push Notification servers only know to direct messages to specific devices.
It is the developer's responsibility to pass the tokens you receive from the

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

method to your server ( through an HTTP post for instance ) and keep track of all the existing tokens.

If/when you want to send a message to all the devices - you simply need to iterate all the existing device tokens.

Comment: how would i do this http post so that i could manage each device token?

Comment: Here you go:
http://www.deanoj.co.uk/ios-development/making-a-http-post-request-with-nsurlconnection/